# How to send sms challenge in OKTA SDK from Angular 13

Tags: angular, okta, okta-api

How to send sms challenge in OKTA SDK from Angular 13

How can I send an sms challenge to the phone number given while enrolling to the factor using Okta.
According to the OKTA documentation I am making a POST call to:

/api/v1/users/${userId}/factors/${factorId}/verify

https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/factors/#request-example-31

This call I am making through the angular HTTP request but its failing with a CORS error. Do I need to add anything to the request headers to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your hosting URL to Trusted Sites in Okta Admin UI, under Security -> Trusted Sites as CORS enabled

Comment: Thanks for your help @Philipp but I have already done that and it still is blocked.